# Having an object contain another object of the same type?

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to create an object that contains an object of the same type. When you create an object of this type, it creates another which creates another and so on until the length is exhausted. However, I get a taking address of temporary warning. How do I get around this?

```
class A {
   A(int len) {
      if(len > 0) {
         _a = & A(len-1);
      }
      else {
         _a = NULL;
      }
   }

   A* _a;
}
```

Comment: From the description, it seems like to create a linked list.

Comment: If you don't really need to have a linked list of objects, you could also try a std::vector of len As.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than taking the address of a temporary, instead create a new object:

```
class A {
   A(int len) {
      if(len > 0) {
         _a = new A(len-1);
      }
      else {
         _a = NULL;
      }
   }

   A* _a;
}
```

Comment: This does what's described.  But then don't forget to take care of `A`'s destructor, copy constructor, and copy assignment operator....

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way where I could get around pointers and have it actually contain an object of itself?

Comment: @Lua: no. But fortunately you shouldn't need to.

Comment: @Lua: and the reason an object can't contain another object of the same type is that in C++, "containing a member" really means *containing* it. The memory occupied by the member is part of the memory occupied by the containing object. So what size could your object possibly be, once you've added some other member data to indicate whether or not this is the end of the line?

Comment: @aschepler: +1, exactly what I meant to say before I got distracted by other things in the "real world". Thanks for mentioning that!